# Golang XML Unmarshalling

Tags: xml, go

```
type Resp struct {
     Count string `xml:"totalRows"`
     Records []interface{} `xml:"data>record"`
}

type DepartmentRecord struct {
     DepID string `xml:"IDFIELD"`
}

type PersonRecord struct {
     UserID string `xml:"IDFIELD"`
}
```

I am looking for a way to pass into xml.Unmarshal Resp struct altered with desired Record type.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please provide a sample of the XML output you'd like to output?

Comment: Please post your yaml along with code you have tried to unmarshal and problem you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to assign slice values of different types to a field you should use `interface{}` instead of `[]interface{}` as the type of the field or else you'll have to convert each element in the slice to interface manually.

```
type Resp struct {
     Count   string      `xml:"totalRows"`
     Records interface{} `xml:"data>record"`
}
```

Now since the type of the field is `interface{}` the xml decoder by itself doesn't know how to unmarshal the xml data and therefore the field is left untouched and unpopulated. To fix this, you can assist the decoder by *pre-allocating* the value of the type you want and assigning it to the field.

```
resp := new(Resp)
resp.Records = new([]DepartmentRecord)
xml.Unmarshal(data, resp)
```

Or if you want to avoid post-unmarshal type assertion on the `Records` field, allocate a variable, assign that to the field, and after unmarshal use the variable.

```
resp := new(Resp)
records := new([]DepartmentRecord)
resp.Records = records
xml.Unmarshal(data, resp)
// records is now populated and ready for use
```

Note that I'm intentionally using `new` on the slice type as opposed to the usual `make`, this is becaues `new` returns an allocated pointer to the zero value of the passed in type and, I belive, the xml decoder needs the underlying type of `interface{}` fields to be pointer types as opposed to value types, which is what `make` would return. So before you use the records slice you'll need to dereference it since it is actaully a pointer.

```
recs := *records
```

I guess a nicer version of the above would be something like this:

```
resp := new(Resp)
records := make([]DepartmentRecord, 0)
resp.Records = &records
xml.Unmarshal(data, resp)
// records is now populated and ready for use
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FHEco6C69jw